# Gallery attachment not found

Tags: gallery

I recently re-made my gallery on my site using the standard Wordpress gallery.

I have noticed an issue when clicking on the images now that it comes up with "attachment not found". I have set the gallery to direct to the attachment page.

This all worked OK before but I noticed the link has now changed. It now shows the URL including the attachment ID but before it had a much more meaningful URL with the image name etc.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out by playing around but it's a bit disappointing that I could find no solutions online. There were a lot of people reporting the issue but with no response.

The images were included in another post which was set to "draft" this for some reason put the images into some kind of hidden state and although I could add them to the gallery and view them when logged in as admin, the links didn't work.

It would probably be better if there was a publish status in the media list to show the status of images etc. if that had been the case I would have spotted the issue early on.